# Distinguishing between plurals and posessives

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Example of what I mean:

> If I have more than one google I have googles, if Google has goggles the goggles are Google's. When Google's down, people get upset.

But if Google's Google's best friend, then this sentence becomes a little confusing.

Is there an elegant solution for this seemingly messy usage of apostrophe's and 's''s?

Comment: Sure. Talk, don't write. Apostrophe's are inaudible, are'nt they?

Answer (score 4):

There is no scenario where you *have* to use "Google's" to mean "Google is" so you can always rewrite the sentence to say "Google is Google's best friend" to avoid the confusion. You can also always rephrase the possessive to clear up ambiguity although it may make your writing sound clunky: "Google is the best friend of Google."